# Special characters display correctly in browser but are scrambled in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, netbeans, mysqli, encoding, phpmyadmin

I have a php netbeans project. The encoding for the project is UTF-8. Special characters display correctly in the ide. (img 1)

I use phpmyadmin and the encoding for the entire database is utf8_unicode_ci (the column also shows this). (img 2)

I use mysqli to connect, and it doesn't make any diference if I call

```
set_caharset("utf8");
```

(img 3)

In the browser everything is ok (including searches with special characters):
(img 4)
But in phpMyAdmin the text introduced through mysqli is scrambled (whilst text introduced manually is ok - id 13 in the picture) (img 5)

[image: encoding problem phpmyadmin mysqli]

What should I do to send text correctly in phpmyadmin.

[edit] Some more info. I don't know how to interpret or use this, bu this is what

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%'
```

displays.

```
Variable_name: Value
character_set_client: utf8mb4
character_set_connection: utf8mb4
character_set_database: latin1
character_set_filesystem: binary
character_set_results: utf8mb4
character_set_server: latin1
character_set_system: utf8
character_sets_dir: D:\Programe\XAMPP\mysql\share\charsets\
```

[edit2] Ok, it is something that is server related. I uploaded the same code that generated the database on a different server and everything is ok. Do you have any ideas where the problem could be?

Comment: Sorry for the formatting. It's my first post and I thought I had new lines after each phrase :(

Comment: @Johan Thank you :) I managed to find the edit button but you were faster than me :D

Comment: I added some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's resolved!

I'm not sure how, because I made multiple modifications before testing.
Where I edited:

- on the front-page of phpmyadmin (localhost/phpmyadmin) under server colation I choose other types of utf8.
- I had a different connection class for the setup where I didn't call: set_caharset("utf8");